# When using stream's read-byte what kind of byte am I reading

Tags: stream, common-lisp

If I this understood correctly, common lisp was standardized in a time when there were many different architectures with different opinions on the size of a byte. To that end common lisp allows us to define the size of a byte.

For example I can create an array of 8bit bytes like this:

`(make-array 10 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))`

This works great and so far this knowledge has been enough for whatever I've been doing.

Today though I've been getting into using binary streams and the `read-byte` function confuses me.

The `CLHS` says that `read-byte reads and returns one byte from stream.`

but what kind of byte is this? The default platform byte? Can I specify this in any way?

Thanks folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example [`OPEN`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_open.htm) has an `:element-type` argument, which is implementation-defined. Your Common Lisp implementation has more informations about it. As said in comments, `(unsigned-byte 8)` describes a stream octets which happens to be the size of bytes in most (all?) implementations. Thanks @Xach.

See also [flexi-streams](http://weitz.de/flexi-streams/) which has `make-external-format` and [binary-types](http://www.cliki.net/binary-types) for custom binary encodings.

Comment: Nice, I was getting the stream from a socket library so I hadn't dug far enough to see the use of `:external-format`. Thanks also for the CLHS links and recommendation of `flexi-streams`.

Comment: :external-format is only relevant for character streams. :element-type is the applicable option for binary streams. In practice (unsigned-byte 8) is the only sane option to get a de facto portable binary stream; smaller or larger bytes are written in implementation-specific ways, but (unsigned-byte 8) has predictable behavior as octets.

Comment: @Xach Thanks, I read the page quickly and somehow confused external-format with element-type.

Answer (score 1):

It is whatever the element type of the stream you read from indicates.

Comment: Nice, I guess that's what [#'stream-element-type](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_stm_el.htm) is for then. Thanks